# javaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'openDatabase'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

This piece of JavaScript code keeps on failing and showing below alert "not supported":

```
 if (!window.openDatabase) 
{
    alert('not supported');
        }
```

Can some one please help out with the solution? This code is used in vb.net aspx page of web application.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `window.openDatabase` is specific to Google Chrome browser and won't work in Firefox, Edge etc. Try using `Local Storage` or `IndexedDB`.